# Recent version(s) of Chrome not remembering GMail password

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

*I haven't had this problem with older versions of Chrome - it started being a issue in recent versions (can't precisely say which version first had it, but let's say, in the past 6 months or so ...)*

Login/password remembering works correctly on most sites, but not on GMail. It "remembers" the login (when you double click on login field it gives you the last used, but it doesn't remember the password.

Checked the do-not-save-for-these-sites password field, GMail is not in there.

*Seen this as an issue already on several forums. I'm aware that it exists. **But I'd like to know whether a solution has been found so far.***

Answer (score 0):

Try an uninstall / reinstall, if that dosen't cure the issue and you can't wait for a fix have you considered a dedicated password manager e.g. [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) or [1password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) ?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall/waiting a bit and then upgrading to a new version hasn't worked. I'm using a password manager (Keepass), but its integration with Chrome has also been buggy (partly their, partly Chrome's fault).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinstalling Chrome I'd suggest re-creating the profile. [Here is how to do it](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059)

Comment: That link is in Polish. The English version is [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059).

Comment: @echristopherson Yep, sorry for that. I corrected my answer